# Where is it prohibited for target object of std::function to throw on destruction?

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer, exception-safety

Consider `std::function` definition:

```cpp
namespace std {
  template<class> class function;       // not defined

  template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
  class function<R(ArgTypes...)> {
  public:
    /* ... */
    template<class F> function(F&&);

    /* ... */

    ~function();

    /* ... */
  };

  /* ... */
}
```

The destructor is not marked explicitly `noexcept`. This declaration is interpreted that it is not `noexcept` in C++14 and it is `noexcept` starting in C++17. Implementations seem to strengthen this and mark in `noexcept` in C++14 (which is allowed): https://godbolt.org/z/WPh8zs7WE

The current draft does not say much about destructor, except that it destroys target object. See [[func.wrap.func.con]/31](https://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap#func.con-31):

> `~function();`
>
> *Effects:* If `*this != nullptr`, destroys the target of this.

Some requirements for target object are listed in constructor parameter, [[func.wrap.func.con]/8](https://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap#func.con-8) through [[func.wrap.func.con]/11](https://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap#func.con-11). Specifically, it is *Lvalue-Callable* and *Cpp17CopyConstructible*.

**However I don't see where it is specified that the target object destructor does not throw.**

Is it specified anywhere?

Or is destructor of `function` not meant to be noexcept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a library-wide requirement, specified in [res.on.functions]:

> In certain cases ([...], operations on types used to instantiate standard
> library template components), the C++ standard library depends on components supplied by a C++ program. If these components do not meet their requirements, this document places no requirements on the implementation.
>
> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - [...]
> - If any [...] destructor operation exits via an exception, unless
>   specifically allowed in the applicable *Required behavior:* paragraph.